# Performance Improvement on Column Header Search and Worksheet Loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, search, columnheader

I have a row of dynamic column headers in the "Summary" tab and 111 worksheets appended at the end of the workbook, although this number is subject to change.  I search for each column header in each appended worksheet and copy the cell immediately beneath any match to its corresponding column and row, a new row for each appended worksheet, in the "Summary" tab.  The output meets my expectations.  The time necessary to loop through every appended worksheet does not.  Please let me know if there are obvious ways to optimize the code or more efficiently achieve my desired results. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub riasummary()
    Dim riawksht        As Worksheet
    Dim consolwksht     As Worksheet
    Dim c               As Integer
    Dim r               As Long
    Dim sheader         As Range
    Dim sheaders        As Range
    Dim rheader         As Range
    Dim rheaders        As Range

    c = Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set sheaders = Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, c))

    For Each riawksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If riawksht.Name <> "Summary" Then
            Set rheaders = riawksht.Range("a5:xfd12")
            For Each rheader In rheaders
                For Each sheader In sheaders
                    r = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
                    If rheader.Value = sheader.Value Then
                        rheader.Offset(1, 0).Copy
                        sheader.Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        'sheader.Offset(1, 0).Value = rheader.Offset(1, 0).Value

                    End If

                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As a tangent, I also occasionally return an "Application-defined or object-defined error" at the following line of code that I cannot seem to decipher, and any insight here would be much appreciated as well.

```
Set sheaders = Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, c))
```

Comment: So your non-summary headers could be anywhere in rows 5 to 12 ?

Comment: More specifically, just rows 5, 9, and 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set sheaders = Sheets("Summary").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, c))
```

Should be:

```
With Sheets("Summary")
     Set sheaders = Sheets("Summary").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, c))
End With
```

You should always avoid unqualified `Cells` or `Range` calls, since they will default (in a regular module) to the active sheet.

Comment: This makes sense and has solved my problem.  Thank you for the clarification.